# I found overload functions in linux man page

Tags: c, overloading

When I man 2 open, I got below:

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

   int creat(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);

   int openat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags);
   int openat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

It is very like function overload. But it is said that C does not support function overload at all. So what is the magic here?

Comment: see this explanation. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/does-c-support-function-overloading/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions aren't really multiple functions, just a single [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic), accepting [variadic arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/variadic), which allows an "overload" in the sense that you can call them with or without their final argument. For example, the actual declaration of `openat` on my system (omitting attribute tags and the like) is:

```
extern int openat (int __fd, const char *__file, int __oflag, ...);
```

That final `...` means it can accept additional arguments via `stdarg.h`'s variable arguments APIs (`va_start`/`va_arg`/`va_end`).

Answer (score 2):

To see the actual definition of these functions, run this command:

```
echo "#include <stdio.h>" | gcc -E - | grep -C5 "open"
```

This will preprocess the one line of source code and tell you what's happening under the hood.

The result should be something like this:

```
int open(const char *, int, ...);
```

This is a typical varargs function like `printf`, but you as the programmer are *supposed* to only ever pass a single argument of type `mode_t`, or none at all.